# Module load intel (ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'intel')

Tags: bash, intel, environment-modules, modulefile

I am trying to use environment-modules in Ubuntu 
I could successfully install the module package but when I tried to use 
`module load intel`,  it gave me the following error:

```
ERROR:105: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'intel'
```

I used `module` avail to see what modules can be available to load 
I got this:

```
- File /home/linux/.local/environment-modules/Modules/versions

    3.2.10

- File /home/linux/.local/environment-modules/Modules/3.2.10/modulefiles

    dot         module-git  module-info modules     null        use.own
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 4):

You do not get module files automatically, you would need to create your own module file in `/home/linux/.local/environment-modules/Modules/3.2.10/modulefiles`, so to get a module named *intel*, you would need to create a file `/home/linux/.local/environment-modules/Modules/3.2.10/modulefiles/intel` with a module description for your intel environment.

Depending on your installation such a module could for example look like this:

```
#%Module -*- tcl -*-
##
## modulefile
##
proc ModulesHelp { } {

  puts stderr "\tAdds Intel compilers to your environment variables,"
}

module-whatis "adds Intel compilers to your environment variables"

set               main_root            /opt/intel/composer_xe/2015.1.133

prepend-path      PATH                 $main_root/bin
prepend-path      PATH                 $main_root/mpirt/bin/intel64
prepend-path      PATH                 $main_root/bin/intel64
prepend-path      PATH                 $main_root/debugger/gdb/intel64/bin
prepend-path      PATH                 $main_root/debugger/gdb/intel64_mic/bin

prepend-path      MANPATH              $main_root/debugger/gdb/intel64_mic/share/man
prepend-path      MANPATH              $main_root/debugger/gdb/intel64/share/man
prepend-path      MANPATH              $main_root/man/en_US

prepend-path      INFOPATH             $main_root/debugger/gdb/intel64_mic/share/info
prepend-path      INFOPATH             $main_root/debugger/gdb/intel64/share/info

prepend-path      LIBRARY_PATH         $main_root/compiler/lib/intel64
prepend-path      LD_LIBRARY_PATH      $main_root/compiler/lib/intel64
prepend-path      LD_LIBRARY_PATH      $main_root/mpirt/lib/intel64
prepend-path      MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH  $main_root/compiler/lib/mic

prepend-path      CPATH                $main_root/compiler/include
prepend-path      CPATH                $main_root/compiler/include/intel64

prepend-path      INTEL_LICENSE_FILE   /cm/shared/licenses/intel

setenv            INTEL_CC_HOME        $main_root
setenv            INTEL_FC_HOME        $main_root
setenv            INTEL_PYTHONHOME     $main_root/debugger/python/intel64
```

You might be interested in using [Lmod](https://www.tacc.utexas.edu/research-development/tacc-projects/lmod/system-administrators-guide/initial-setup-of-modules) for your modules environment.